# Firefox a.click won't fire without a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, firefox, download, click, anchor

I'm working on a project where we have an AJAX call which responds with a blob containing an excel file.  I want the code to open the file as a download when I get the response.  Here is the callback:

```
var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var a = document.createElement("a");
var header = response.headers("Content-Disposition");
a.download = header.substring(header.indexOf("filename=") + "filename=".length);
a.href = objectUrl;
document.body.appendChild(a);
console.debug("Clicking a tag");
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
```

This code works fine in chrome but in firefox nothing happens when a.click() fires.  The debug statement prints so I know that the callback is happening.  Also, for some reason, if I put a breakpoint on `a.click()` it works perfectly.

Can someone explain why the click only works in debug mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox has a couple of safeguards or just odd behaviors around things like this. I don't know the derivation, but yielding back to the browser for a moment before doing the click usually clears it up:

```
// ...
a.href = objectUrl;
document.body.appendChild(a);
setTimeout(function() {
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
}, 0);
// ...
```

Note that code following the `setTimeout` will run *before* the content of the `setTimeout` does.

You might even need two:

```
// ...
a.href = objectUrl;
document.body.appendChild(a);
setTimeout(function() {
    a.click();
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
    }, 0);
}, 0);
// ...
```

Comment: @user2752635: I may be misremembering, you may need it *after* the `click`. I've added an example with it in both places above. I also remember having something in Firefox about a year ago where a `0` timeout didn't work but a `10` timeout didn't. (At which point I decided to rethink my entire approach, as I wasn't comfortable with that... :-) )

Comment: This fixes the problem for me.  I don't like have `setTimeout(fn, 0)`'s  in my code (especially nested) but if it works it works.

Comment: Also, I tried without the first and it didn't work.  It needs both.

Comment: Wow. Yeah, sometimes you need to yield back for it to work properly. Seems like a bug to me, in this particular case. Other cases it's reasonable, but...

Comment: @user2752635: I probably don't have to say this, but: Do be sure to test thoroughly in case it only works intermittently. That's what happened to me with the case I mentioned above where it only became reliable at 10ms and I went another way.

Comment: I had to add two setTimeouts as you wrote. FF v 45.2